# Best way to serve / produce silhoutte of the US States?

Tags: svg, png, maps, visualization, protovis

I'm responsible for delivering pages to display primary results for the US elections State by State.  Each page needs a banner with an image of the State, approx 250px by 250px.  Now all I need to do is figure out how to serve / generate those images...

1. I've dug into the docs / examples for [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/choropleth.html) and think I
   could probably lift the State coordinate outlines- I would have to
   manually transform the coordinate data to be justified and sized
   properly (ick)
2. At the other end of the clever/brute spectrum is an enormous sprite
   or series of sprites.  Even with png 8 compression the file size of
   a grid of 50 non-overlapping 250x250px sprites is a concern, and
   sadly such a file doesn't seem to exist so I'd have to create it
   from hand.  Also unpleasant.

**Who's got a better idea?**

Answered: the right solution is to switch to d3.

What we hacked in for now:

```
 drawStateInBox = function(box, state, color) {
   var w = $("#" + box).width(),
           h = $("#" + box).height(),
           off_x = 0,
           off_y = 0;
           borders = us_lowres[state].borders;

   //Preserve aspect ratio
   delta_lat = pv.max(borders[0], function(b) b.lat) - pv.min(borders[0], function(b) b.lat);
   delta_lng = pv.max(borders[0], function(b) b.lng) - pv.min(borders[0], function(b) b.lng);

   if (delta_lat / h > delta_lng / w) {
     scaled_h = h;
     scaled_w = w * delta_lat / delta_lng;
     off_x = (w - scaled_w) / 2;
   } else {
     scaled_h = h * delta_lat / delta_lng;
     scaled_w = w;
     off_y = (h - scaled_h) / 2;
   }

   var scale = pv.Geo.scale()
           .domain(us_lowres[state].borders[0])
           .range({x: off_x, y: off_y},
           {x: scaled_w + off_x, y: scaled_h + off_y});


   var vis = new pv.Panel(state)
           .canvas(box)
           .width(w)
           .height(h)
           .data(borders)
           .add(pv.Line)
           .data(function(l) l)
           .left(scale.x)
           .top(scale.y)
           .fillStyle(function(d, l, c) {
             return(color);
           })
           .lineWidth(0)
           .strokeStyle(color)
           .antialias(false);

   vis.render();
 };
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually transform' coord data in (1)? And how compatible does this need to be (canvas != IE6...)?

Comment: I have moral objections to writing code for IE6 compatibility, thankfully it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.html) seems to have the capability to do maps similar to what you want.  The example shows both counties and states so you would just omit the counties and then provide the election results in the right format.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you would do this from that link.  Is there an example?

Comment: You could filter the us-states.json file for one state. You could also remove the logic related to us-counties.json.

Comment: This is probably the right answer.  We aren't ready to switch from protovis to d3 yet, but the writing is on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of maps on 50states.com, e.g. http://www.50states.com/maps/alabama.htm, which is about 5KB. Roughly, then, that's 250KB for the whole set. Since you mention using these separately, there's your answer.

Or are you doing more with this than just showing the outline?